# How to make axes vertical in ggparcoord function?

Tags: r, axes

How can I make the x-axis labels vertical in ggparcord when I have something similar to this code?

```
ggparcoord(mtcars,columns=2:11,groupColumn=1)
```

I tried:

```
ggparcoord(mtcars,columns=2:11,groupColumn=1,las=1)
```

to receive an error:

```
Error in ggparcoord(mtcars, columns = 2:11, groupColumn = 1, las = 1) : 
  unused argument (las = 1)
```

I also tried:

```
ggparcoord(mtcars,columns=2:11,groupColumn=1,axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))
```

to receive an error:

```
Error in ggparcoord(mtcars, columns = 2:11, groupColumn = 1, axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) : 
  unused argument (axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the rotation of the x-axis labels in the `theme` function:

```
library(GGally)
ggparcoord(mtcars, columns = 2:11, groupColumn = 1) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image]